# Optimize R Script

Tags: r, ggplot2

I created this script to dynamically generate QAQC charts in Power BI. The script works perfectly, but consumes a lot of Power BI capacity. I wanted to know if there is any way to optimize the script improving the performance of building the graphic.

Basically, I have a parameter in Power BI that switches which type of graph will be generated by the script and thus generate the visualization within Power BI.

**Dataset**

```
dataset = structure(list(ASSAYVALUE_CK = c(3.1, 4.9, 5.3, 7.7, 14.4, 16.8, 
37.6, 47.4, 54, 107.5, 121.5, 125, 135.5, 152.5, 159.5, 181, 
205, 237, 240, 245, 248, 320, 366, 504, 649, 697, 713, 811, 1025, 
1090, 1175, 1255, 2030, 2380, 2400, 3260, 5310, 6850, 8860), 
    ASSAYVALUE_OR = c(2.7, 5.4, 5.6, 9.4, 16.3, 20.4, 41.7, 44.2, 
    48.3, 124.5, 126.5, 111, 139, 131, 155, 201, 213, 237, 234, 
    260, 240, 298, 360, 557, 675, 669, 729, 809, 1030, 1135, 
    1110, 1285, 2010, 2420, 2550, 3180, 4530, 6810, 8920), QAQC_STATUS = c("To check", 
    "To check", "Passed", "To check", "To check", "To check", 
    "To check", "Passed", "To check", "To check", "Passed", "To check", 
    "Passed", "To check", "Passed", "To check", "Passed", "Passed", 
    "Passed", "Passed", "Passed", "Passed", "Passed", "To check", 
    "Passed", "Passed", "Passed", "Passed", "Passed", "Passed", 
    "Passed", "Passed", "Passed", "Passed", "Passed", "Passed", 
    "To check", "Passed", "Passed"), ASSAYNAME = c("Cu_ME-MS61_ppm", 
    "Cu_ME-MS61_ppm", "Cu_ME-MS61_ppm", "Cu_ME-MS61_ppm", "Cu_ME-MS61_ppm", 
    "Cu_ME-MS61_ppm", "Cu_ME-MS61_ppm", "Cu_ME-MS61_ppm", "Cu_ME-MS61_ppm", 
    "Cu_ME-MS61_ppm", "Cu_ME-MS61_ppm", "Cu_ME-MS61_ppm", "Cu_ME-MS61_ppm", 
    "Cu_ME-MS61_ppm", "Cu_ME-MS61_ppm", "Cu_ME-MS61_ppm", "Cu_ME-MS61_ppm", 
    "Cu_ME-MS61_ppm", "Cu_ME-MS61_ppm", "Cu_ME-MS61_ppm", "Cu_ME-MS61_ppm", 
    "Cu_ME-MS61_ppm", "Cu_ME-MS61_ppm", "Cu_ME-MS61_ppm", "Cu_ME-MS61_ppm", 
    "Cu_ME-MS61_ppm", "Cu_ME-MS61_ppm", "Cu_ME-MS61_ppm", "Cu_ME-MS61_ppm", 
    "Cu_ME-MS61_ppm", "Cu_ME-MS61_ppm", "Cu_ME-MS61_ppm", "Cu_ME-MS61_ppm", 
    "Cu_ME-MS61_ppm", "Cu_ME-MS61_ppm", "Cu_ME-MS61_ppm", "Cu_ME-MS61_ppm", 
    "Cu_ME-MS61_ppm", "Cu_ME-MS61_ppm"), CHECKSTAGE_CK = c("C", 
    "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
    "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
    "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
    "C", "C"), ID_CK = c("PKC-ARRA-DH00001-0383", "PKC-ARRA-DH00001-0359", 
    "PKC-ARRA-DH00001-0151", "PKC-ARRA-DH00001-0111", "PKC-ARRA-DH00004-0402", 
    "PKC-ARRA-DH00001-0069", "PKC-ARRA-DH00001-0045", "PKC-ARRA-DH00007-0361", 
    "PKC-ARRA-DH00001-0207", "PKC-ARRA-DH00007-0408", "PKC-ARRA-DH00007-0204", 
    "PKC-ARRA-DH00005-0342", "PKC-ARRA-DH00001-0336", "PKC-ARRA-DH00001-0265", 
    "PKC-ARRA-DH00007-0314", "PKC-ARRA-DH00005-0412", "PKC-ARRA-DH00004-0298", 
    "PKC-ARRA-DH00004-0280", "PKC-ARRA-DH00005-0090", "PKC-ARRA-DH00007-0157", 
    "PKC-ARRA-DH00004-0419", "PKC-ARRA-DH00005-0367", "PKC-ARRA-DH00005-0454", 
    "PKC-ARRA-DH00006-0153", "PKC-ARRA-DH00007-0178", "PKC-ARRA-DH00007-0254", 
    "PKC-ARRA-DH00007-0272", "PKC-ARRA-DH00006-0172", "PKC-ARRA-DH00004-0192", 
    "PKC-ARRA-DH00005-0138", "PKC-ARRA-DH00005-0177", "PKC-ARRA-DH00004-0205", 
    "PKC-ARRA-DH00004-0221", "PKC-ARRA-DH00007-0105", "PKC-ARRA-DH00004-0356", 
    "PKC-ARRA-DH00005-0299", "PKC-ARRA-DH00004-0261", "PKC-ARRA-DH00005-0220", 
    "PKC-ARRA-DH00005-0258"), Mean_Pairs = c(2.9, 5.15, 5.45, 
    8.55, 15.35, 18.6, 39.65, 45.8, 51.15, 116, 124, 118, 137.25, 
    141.75, 157.25, 191, 209, 237, 237, 252.5, 244, 309, 363, 
    530.5, 662, 683, 721, 810, 1027.5, 1112.5, 1142.5, 1270, 
    2020, 2400, 2475, 3220, 4920, 6830, 8890), MPRD_Color = c("Warning", 
    "Normal", "Normal", "Warning", "Warning", "Warning", "Warning", 
    "Normal", "Warning", "Warning", "Normal", "Warning", "Normal", 
    "Warning", "Normal", "Warning", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal", 
    "Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal", 
    "Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal", 
    "Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Warning", 
    "Normal", "Normal"), MPRD = c(-13.79, 9.71, 5.5, 19.88, 12.38, 
    19.35, 10.34, -6.99, -11.14, 14.66, 4.03, -11.86, 2.55, -15.17, 
    -2.86, 10.47, 3.83, 0, -2.53, 5.94, -3.28, -7.12, -1.65, 
    9.99, 3.93, -4.1, 2.22, -0.25, 0.49, 4.04, -5.69, 2.36, -0.99, 
    1.67, 6.06, -2.48, -15.85, -0.59, 0.67), QTD_LD = c(1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Chart_Type = c("P-Scatter", 
    "P-Scatter", "P-Scatter", "P-Scatter", "P-Scatter", "P-Scatter", 
    "P-Scatter", "P-Scatter", "P-Scatter", "P-Scatter", "P-Scatter", 
    "P-Scatter", "P-Scatter", "P-Scatter", "P-Scatter", "P-Scatter", 
    "P-Scatter", "P-Scatter", "P-Scatter", "P-Scatter", "P-Scatter", 
    "P-Scatter", "P-Scatter", "P-Scatter", "P-Scatter", "P-Scatter", 
    "P-Scatter", "P-Scatter", "P-Scatter", "P-Scatter", "P-Scatter", 
    "P-Scatter", "P-Scatter", "P-Scatter", "P-Scatter", "P-Scatter", 
    "P-Scatter", "P-Scatter", "P-Scatter"), TYPE = c("Coarse Dup", 
    "Coarse Dup", "Coarse Dup", "Coarse Dup", "Coarse Dup", "Coarse Dup", 
    "Coarse Dup", "Coarse Dup", "Coarse Dup", "Coarse Dup", "Coarse Dup", 
    "Coarse Dup", "Coarse Dup", "Coarse Dup", "Coarse Dup", "Coarse Dup", 
    "Coarse Dup", "Coarse Dup", "Coarse Dup", "Coarse Dup", "Coarse Dup", 
    "Coarse Dup", "Coarse Dup", "Coarse Dup", "Coarse Dup", "Coarse Dup", 
    "Coarse Dup", "Coarse Dup", "Coarse Dup", "Coarse Dup", "Coarse Dup", 
    "Coarse Dup", "Coarse Dup", "Coarse Dup", "Coarse Dup", "Coarse Dup", 
    "Coarse Dup", "Coarse Dup", "Coarse Dup"), QAQCParameter = c(10L, 
    10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
    10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
    10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
    10L, 10L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -39L))
```

**Script**

```
library("ggplot2")
library("dplyr")

pcttxt = unique(dataset$QAQCParameter)
pct = (pcttxt / 100)
txt1 = paste(pcttxt, "% Diference", sep="")
txt2 = paste(pcttxt*2, "% Diference", sep="")

if(all(unique(dataset$Chart_Type) == "P-Scatter")){ 
  
    n = length(unique(dataset$QAQC_STATUS))
    total_linhas = length(unique(dataset$ID_CK))
    
    legenda = c("X=Y" = "black", 
                "Warning" = "goldenrod3", 
                "Error" = "red3", 
                "To check" = "red", 
                "Passed" = "blue")
    
    names(legenda) = c("X=Y",  "Warning",  "Error",  "To check", "Passed")
                          
    if (n == 0) {
      p = ggplot() + theme_minimal()
      
    }else {
            linhas_ref <- list(stat_function(fun = function(x) x, size=0.8, linetype = "dashed", aes(colour = "X=Y")),
                               stat_function(fun = function(x) (1-(pct))*x, linetype = "dashed", aes(colour = "Warning")),
                               stat_function(fun = function(x) (1+(pct))*x, linetype = "dashed", aes(colour = "Warning")),
                               stat_function(fun = function(x) (1-(pct*2))*x, aes(colour = "Error")),
                               stat_function(fun = function(x) (1+(pct*2))*x, aes(colour = "Error")))
            
            if (n == 1) {
              type_line = c("dashed", "solid", "blank", "dashed")
              type_shape = c(NA, NA, 18, NA)
              legenda = legenda[ifelse(names(legenda[4]) ==  unique(dataset$QAQC_STATUS), -5, -4)]
              
            }else {
              type_line = c("dashed", "solid", "blank", "blank", "dashed")
              type_shape = c(NA, NA, 18, 18, NA)
            }
            
            titulo = unique(paste("ALS", dataset$ASSAYNAME,  
                                         unique(paste0(dataset$CHECKSTAGE_CK,'.Stage: P-Scatter (n=', total_linhas, ')')),
                                         sep = " - "))
            
      
            p <- ggplot(dataset, aes(ASSAYVALUE_OR, ASSAYVALUE_CK, color=(QAQC_STATUS))) +
                 geom_point(size=2.5, shape=18) +
                 linhas_ref +
                
                 scale_colour_manual(values = legenda,
                                      guide = guide_legend(override.aes = list(linetype = type_line,
                                                                               shape = type_shape))) +
                 labs(title = titulo,  x = "Original",  y = "Check", colour = 'Legend: ') + 
                
                 theme_bw() +
                 theme(legend.position="bottom", plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
                 expand_limits(x=0, y=0)
              
      }
      p
    
  
}else if (all(unique(dataset$Chart_Type) == "RD by Mean Grade")){
   
    dataset <- subset(dataset, dataset$QTD_LD == 1)
   
    n = length(unique(dataset$MPRD_Color))
    total_linhas = length(unique(dataset$ID_CK))
    
    if (n == 0){
       p = ggplot () + theme_minimal()
       
    }else{
        titulo = unique(paste("ALS",  dataset$ASSAYNAME,  
                                      unique(paste0(dataset$CHECKSTAGE_CK,'.Stage: RD by Mean Grade (n=', total_linhas, ')')),
                                      sep = " - "))
    
        type_label_lines = c(txt1, txt2)
        type_label_point = as.character(unique(dataset$MPRD_Color))
        
        type_all_label = c(type_label_lines, type_label_point)
        type_shape = c(NA, NA, rep(18, length(type_label_point)))
        
        idcores = rep(1, length(type_all_label))
        idcores[type_all_label == txt1] = "goldenrod3"
        idcores[type_all_label == txt2] ="red3"
        idcores[type_all_label == "Warning"] ="goldenrod3"
        idcores[type_all_label == "Error"] = "red"
        idcores[type_all_label == "Normal"] = "blue"
        
        fun <- function(ref, cor){
          cor <- as.character(cor)
          x <- unique(ref)
          i <- match(x, ref)
          setNames(cor[i], ref[i])
        }
        
        color_ref = fun(type_all_label, idcores)
    
    
    p = ggplot(dataset, aes(Mean_Pairs, MPRD, color=(MPRD_Color))) +
        geom_point(size=2.5, shape=18) +
        
        #scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(-1000,1000,10)) +
        ylim(-100,100) +
       
        geom_line(mapping=aes( y = pcttxt, color = txt1), linetype = "dashed", size = 0.8) +
        geom_line(mapping=aes( y = (-1 * pcttxt), color = txt1), linetype = "dashed", size = 0.8) +
        geom_line(mapping=aes( y = (pcttxt * 2), color = txt2), linetype = "dashed", size = 0.8) +
        geom_line(mapping=aes( y = -1 * (pcttxt * 2), color = txt2), linetype = "dashed", size = 0.8) +
      
        scale_colour_manual(values = color_ref,
                             guide = guide_legend(override.aes = list(shape = type_shape))) +
        labs(title = titulo,
             #subtitle = "...",
             #caption = "...",
             #tag = "Figure 1",
             x = "Mean",
             y = "MPRD (%)",
             colour = 'Legend: ') + 
      
        theme_bw() +
        theme(legend.position="bottom", plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
    }
    p
    
    
}else {

    dataset <- subset(dataset, dataset$QTD_LD == 1)
    n = length(unique(dataset$MPRD_Color))
    total_linhas = length(unique(dataset$ID_CK))
    
    if (n == 0) {
      p = ggplot() + theme_minimal()
      
    }else { 
        titulo = unique(paste("ALS",  dataset$ASSAYNAME,  
                                      unique(paste0(dataset$CHECKSTAGE_CK,'.Stage: RD by Percentile (n=', total_linhas, ')')),
                                      sep = " - "))
      
        dataset$percent = order_by(abs(dataset$MPRD), cumsum(abs(dataset$Mean_Pairs)/sum(abs(dataset$Mean_Pairs))))*100
        
        type_label_lines = c(txt1, txt2)
        type_label_point = as.character(unique(dataset$MPRD_Color))
        
        type_all_label = c(type_label_lines, type_label_point)
        type_shape = c(NA, NA, rep(18, length(type_label_point)))
        
        idcores = rep(1, length(type_all_label))
        idcores[type_all_label == txt1] = "goldenrod3"
        idcores[type_all_label == txt2] ="red3"
        idcores[type_all_label == "Warning"] ="goldenrod3"
        idcores[type_all_label == "Error"] = "red"
        idcores[type_all_label == "Normal"] = "blue"
        
        fun <- function(ref, cor){
          cor <- as.character(cor)
          x <- unique(ref)
          i <- match(x, ref)
          setNames(cor[i], ref[i])
        }
        
        color_ref = fun(type_all_label, idcores)
        
        
        p = ggplot(dataset, aes(percent, abs(MPRD), color=(MPRD_Color))) +
            geom_point(size=2, shape=18) +
            
            geom_line(mapping=aes( y = pcttxt, color = txt1), linetype = "dashed", size = 0.8) +
            geom_line(mapping=aes( y = (pcttxt*2), color = txt2), linetype = "dashed", size = 0.8) +
            
            scale_colour_manual(values = color_ref,
                                guide = guide_legend(override.aes = list(shape = type_shape))) +
            labs(title = titulo,
                 #subtitle = "...",
                 #caption = "...",
                 #tag = "Figure 1",
                 x = "Percent Population",
                 y = "Absolute MPRD",
                 colour = 'Legend: ') + 
            
            theme_bw() +
            theme(legend.position="bottom", plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
      }
      p
}
```

Comment: I don't see anything that's obviously slow. I would suggest [profiling your code](https://support.posit.co/hc/en-us/articles/218221837-Profiling-R-code-with-the-RStudio-IDE) to see where the slow bits are. But you won't be able to do much to speed up `ggplot`.